# How to remove program which I still see in GNOME Dash after uninstalling it?

Tags: apt, gnome, software-installation, uninstall, repository

The title may be a bit confusing so let me explain my situation.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and quite a while ago (I think when I was still on 19.10) I installed the program "Fritzing". I now want to install a newer version (downloaded a dev version from GitHub), so to keep things clean I first want to remove this old version.

I'm not sure how I installed it back then, but it showed up when I hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and typed "Fritz". I also found a folder called "fritzing" in `~/bin/fritzing/`. That makes sense, because, occasionally, if there is no other obvious alternative, I place binaries there. So assuming that the item I saw when I searched for Fritzing in GNOME, is the binary in `~/bin/fritzing/`, I removed that folder with `rm -rf ~/bin/fritzing/`. The folder with the binary is gone, but I can still start Fritzing by hitting the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and searching for "Fritzing".

So I then opened the Ubuntu Software UI and searched for "Fritzing". There are two entries there; one from `ubuntu-focal-universe` and one from `dl.flathub.org`. It says the first one (from focal-universe) is installed. So I hit the remove button and then it failed saying "no packages to remove".

I'm now after this installed version to completely nuke it, but I just can't find it.

I tried `which fritzing` and `which Fritzing` (because the binary in the GitHub releases is with a capital "F") and also `sudo apt purge fritzing`, but nothing works.

I'm kinda lost now. How can I find out where this menu item in the Gnome search refers to? Where are these defined?

Answer (score 2):

Applications that appear in GNOME Dash (also in the menus of other desktop environments) usually have a `.desktop` file either in `~/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications`.

Sometimes, if you don't install an application with `apt`, some `.desktop` files may remain in these places as leftovers.

Just delete the `.desktop` file corresponding to the application you want to remove from the Dash (Fritzing in your case) from the aforementioned places and your issue should be solved.